# Importing .txt file with game results and outputting a file with team records

Tags: java, import, export

I have made some progress on a program that reads a .txt file:

### soccer

```
Lions Panthers Tigers Sky
Panthers    4   Tigers      3
Tigers      3   Lions       1
Sky         2   Panthers    0
Lions       2   Tigers      1
Tigers      1   Sky         6
Sky         2   Panthers    1
Tigers      1   Sky         4
Panthers    3   Tigers      6
Lions       3   Sky         2
Tigers      4   Sky         3
Sky         2   Panthers    1
Lions       4   Panthers    6
```

Then out puts the win/loss records of each team in a new file "results.txt":

### results

```
Team        Wins        Losses
Lions       2            2
Panthers    2            4  
Sky         5            2
Tigers      3            4
```

So far my code does not properly keep track of each teams and losses. I began writing what will certainly be an extensive chain of if-else statements, but am not getting any results. There must be a better way of doing this that i am missing. here is what i have so far:

```
 import java.io.*;   
 import java.util.*;

public class Soccer
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    //initiate an input file object and scanner object
    File inData = new File("soccer.txt");
    if(!inData.exists())
    {
      System.out.println("File does not exist");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inData);

    //create output file and a printWriter object
    File outData = new File("results.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outData);


    String teamName1 = input.next();
    int wins1 = 0;
    int loses1 = 0;
    String teamName2 = input.next();
    int wins2 = 0;
    int loses2 = 0;
    String teamName3 = input.next();
    int wins3 = 0;
    int loses3 = 0;
    String teamName4 = input.next();
    int wins4 = 0;
    int loses4 = 0;

    while(input.hasNext())
    {
      String teamOne = input.next();
      int scoreOne = input.nextInt();
      String teamTwo = input.next();
      int scoreTwo = input.nextInt();
  
      if(scoreOne>scoreTwo && teamOne==teamName1)
      {
        wins1++;
      }
      else if(scoreOne<scoreTwo && teamOne==teamName1)
      {
        loses1++;
      }
    }    
    output.println("Team\t\tWins\t\tLosses");
    output.println(teamName1+"\t\t"+wins1+"\t\t"+loses1);
    output.println(teamName2+"\t"+wins2+"\t\t"+loses2);
    output.println(teamName3+"\t\t"+wins3+"\t\t"+loses3);
    output.println(teamName4+"\t\t"+wins4+"\t\t"+loses4);

    input.close();
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself with a bunch of variables (of the same type) called `foo1`, `foo2`, etc., you should replace them with a `List` or array of that type and reference the different values by index.

Comment: Since you also want to have win/loss information associated with a team, I strongly urge you to create a `Team` class which contains the team's name, wins, losses, etc. to store this information, rather than trying to keep track of it all piecemeal.